# Hibernate query caching with named queries with hibernate 3

Tags: hibernate

How can I enable query caching in hibernate when using named queries is it different from usual query caching enabling

Answer (score 1):

In your hibernate configurations (persistence.xml or spring SessionFactoryBean definitions)
defined the following properties

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
```

It’s relevant both for named queries and for other hibernate queries.
Note that the query cache should always be used in conjunction with the second-level cache..

See also:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html#d0e2601
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/4/html/ch04s02s03.html